# Jquery to replace <span> text with an image

Tags: jquery

I currently have this code for an online store shopping cart:

```
<span class="ShoppingList_RemoveCheckBox">
<a onclick="document.My_Account_Shopping_List_Detail_Content.rcuid.value="475";
document.My_Account_Shopping_List_Detail_Content.FormSubmittedByLink.value="submittedByRemoveLink"; document.My_Account_Shopping_List_Detail_Content.submit(); return false;" href="noURL">Remove </a>
</span>
```

What I need to do is replace the "Remove" text with an image, so the user can click on the image to remove an item from the shopping cart.

How can I do this without affecting the function of the rest of the link?

I've tried first selecting the content with this:

```
$(".ShoppingList_RemoveCheckBox").filter(function(){
return $(this).html() == "a";
```

To select the code, but then I'm not sure if there's a way to change the text ONLY. I know there's the .text() Jquery, but don't you have to have a specific id to reference for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ShoppingList_RemoveCheckBox a').html('<img src="remove.gif" />')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.ShoppingList_RemoveCheckBox a:contains(Remove)").html($("<img/>", { src: imageURL }));
```